# VB NET Convert Date Format

Tags: sql, vb.net, date

Just wondering if someone could please point me in the right direction.

In my SQL database, I have a Date column, and the format of the date is:

> yyyy/MM/dd - e.g. 2014/07/31

I want to keep this format in my SQL database.

However, when I query it through my VB NET project I want to display the date in a different format.

> dd/MM/yyyy - e.g. 31/07/2014

Is there anyway to do this through .NET as opposed to doing the conversion through SQL?

If someone can help that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `myDt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`  Dates do not have a format, they are simple displayed in various formats as needed.  Both the SQL date column and date variable are actually a number (value), formats do not change that value, simply how it is displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
someDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```